# Can't render out my node effect

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, scene

I had just recently switch from blender render to cycles and am having trouble with the node editor.I want some mist on my animation background.As you can see from the picture below , I did it but when i render it out to png , it does not have the effect that shows in the node editor. How do i get the effect for the png rendering?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your node setup the viewer is connected to a mix node and the composite is not.

Plug the composite to the output of the mix node to it as well!

[image]